# How to make a triple equivalence dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to make a mapping between the grade categories in the picture below. Then I would like to be able to call a function that converts a grade to the same grade in an equivalent format. Ex:

```
def convert(num, letter, gpa):
    """Converts a grade into an equivalent grade. The desired output will be 
    specified by -1 and the grade format not to be involved in the conversion 
    will be specified by None. When converting to GPA, the minimum of the gpa 
    range will be returned."""
    >>> convert(83, None, -1)
    >>> 'A-'
    >>>convert(-1, 'B+', None) 
    >>>77
```

I thought of making three parallel lists for the equivalence and then the function would end up using a bunch of if statements. What's the best way to do this?

[image]

Comment: How about a table in the database?

Comment: Since you can't go from column 3 to column 1, it makes the most sense to me to have 2 dictionaries, both with the keys being the letter grades. {'A+':(90, 100), 'A':(85,89)} and you're going to want to think about what you do with 89.5 etc.

Comment: There are dictionary tricks that you can do here, but I don't know that that would be necessary given the very little data you have. Just accept your args without using the -1 convention. Loop through an ordered tuple of tuples. Return the first one that fits.

Comment: @Mauve This function should be able to go from any column to any other column.

Comment: @Jonathan Oh?  Which value in column 1 does `4.0` map to?

Comment: @JacobG., It maps to 90

Comment: @Jonathan Why not 85?

Comment: Oh right, I didn't notice the double 4.0. Lets just skip the case of the 4.0

Comment: @Jonathan are you married to the None -1 convention for converting or would a convert function with a different signature be fine?

Comment: @MoxieBall a different convention would be fine. I just thought that one would be easy.

Comment: @Jonathan What are your thoughts on not having a single `convert` function, but rather different functions to convert between the two values that you're concerned with (instead of all three)?

Comment: @GeorgeK I've never heard of this database table. Could you point me a link to exactly what you're talking about?

Comment: @JacobG. That would be fine. I'm really just looking for any kind of efficient solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably do something like this, it avoids conditional branching and makes it abundantly clear what you are trying to do when you convert.

```
class GradeRange:
    def __init__(self, pct, ltr, gpa):
        self.pct = pct
        self.ltr = ltr
        self.gpa = gpa

class GradeTable:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ranges = [
            GradeRange(range(0,  50), 'F',  0.0),
            GradeRange(range(50, 53), 'D-', 0.7),
            GradeRange(range(53, 57), 'D',  1.0),
            GradeRange(range(57, 60),  'D+', 1.3),
            GradeRange(range(60, 63), 'C-', 1.7),
            GradeRange(range(63, 67), 'C', 2.0),
            GradeRange(range(67, 70), 'C+', 2.3),
            GradeRange(range(70, 73), 'B-', 2.7),
            GradeRange(range(73, 77), 'B', 3.0),
            GradeRange(range(77, 80), 'B+', 3.3),
            GradeRange(range(80, 85), 'A-', 3.7),
            GradeRange(range(85, 90), 'A', 4.0),
            GradeRange(range(90, 101), 'A+', 4.0),
        ]

    def convert_pct(self, pct):
        for r in self.ranges:
            if pct in r.pct:
                return r.ltr, r.gpa

    def convert_ltr(self, ltr):
        for r in self.ranges:
            if r.ltr == ltr:
                return r.pct[0], r.gpa

    def convert_gpa(self, gpa):
        for r in self.ranges:
            if r.gpa == gpa:
                return r.pct[0], r.ltr
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks pretty nice!

Comment: Since `GradeRange`s are only used inside `GradeTable` (and its output is always a tuple), it seems reasonable to define it inside `GradeTable`. Also: why would you need multiple `GradeTables`? Maybe tweak it so `__init__` accepts a list of tuples to override `self.ranges`?

Comment: I did this, but without the classes. It didn't seem necessary.

Comment: @Adam Smith just didn't want to have to reference them as `GradeTable.GradeRange`. And you are right, probably wouldn't need multiple, and accepting a list of tuples would be nice for sure, just didn't seem necessary to answer the question about general organization

Answer (score 2):

You could make this an enum of results

```
from enum import Enum

class GradeResults(Enum):
    A_PLUS = ("A+", 4.3, range(90, 101))
    A = ("A", 4.0, range(85, 90))
    A_MINUS = ("A-", 3.7, range(80, 85))
    # etc

    @classmethod
    def from_lettergrade(cls, lett):
        for gr in cls:
            if lett == gr.lettergrade:
                return gr
        raise ValueError("Invalid letter grade.")

    @classmethod
    def from_gpa(cls, gpa):
        for gr in cls:
            if gpa == gr.gpa:
                return gr
        raise ValueError("Invalid GPA.")

    @classmethod
    def from_percentage(cls, pct):
        for gr in cls:
            if pct in gr.percentage:
                return gr
        raise ValueError("Percentage out of range.")

    @property
    def lettergrade(self):
        return self.value[0]

    @property
    def gpa(self):
        return self.value[1]

    @property
    def percentage(self):
        return self.value[2]
```

This lets you do things like:

```
result = GradeResults.from_gpa(4.0)
# result is now GradeResults.A

result.percentage
# range(85, 90)

class_grades = [GradeResults.from_percentage(pct).lettergrade
                for pct in some_existing_list_of_class_percentages]
```

and of course:

```
an_a_plus = GradeResults["A_PLUS"]  # or GradeResults.A_PLUS
a_c_minus = GradeResults.C_MINUS
a_c_minus == an_a_plus  # False
```

You could even play with the order of the tuple (`(GPA, letter grade, then range)` would probably work best) and inherit `enum.OrderedEnum` and you could do:

```
a_c_minus < an_a_plus  # True
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion:

```
grades = (
 ((90, 100), 'A+', 4.0),
 ((85, 89), 'A', 4.0),
 ((80, 84), 'A-', 3.7),
 ((77, 79), 'B+', 3.3),
 ((73, 76), 'B', 3.0),
 ((70, 72), 'B-', 2.7),
 ((67, 69), 'C+', 2.3),
 ((63, 66), 'C', 2.0),
 ((60, 62), 'C-', 1.7),
 ((57, 59), 'D+', 1.3),
 ((53, 56), 'D', 1.0),
 ((50, 52), 'D-', 0.7),
 ((0, 49), 'F', 0.0))

def convert(num=None, letter=None, gpa=None):
    for scores, alpha, number in grades:
        low, high = scores
        if (
            (num is None or low <= num <= high) and
            (letter is None or letter == alpha) and
            (gpa is None or gpa >= number)): break
    else:
        return 'No match'
    return scores, alpha, number

convert(num = 83)

>>   ((80, 84), 'A-', 3.7)

convert(letter = 'B+')

>>   ((77, 79), 'B+', 3.3)
```